# Extract Json Key value using grep or regex

Tags: json, linux

I need to extract the value for request ID in the below json message

```
{"requestId":"2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1"}
```

I don't have JQ command in my OS. Is there another way I can do it, possibly using grep regex or something else?

```
{"requestId":"2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1"}
```

I need to extract the value 2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1

Comment: Is the JSON object as simple as what you have there? Or are there other keys? The structure of the text is important if you actually wanna use text processing methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question

```
#!/bin/bash

CURL_OUTPUT="{\"requestId\":\"2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1\"}"

echo $CURL_OUTPUT | awk -F: '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' | sed 's/"//g;'
```

Second question

```
#!/bin/bash

CURL_OUTPUT="{\"status\":\"INITIALIZED\",\"result\":\"NONE\"}"

status=$(echo $CURL_OUTPUT | awk -F, '{print $1}' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g')
result=$(echo $CURL_OUTPUT | awk -F, '{print $2}' | awk -F: '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' | sed 's/"//g')

echo "CURL_OUTPUT: $CURL_OUTPUT"
echo "Status: $status" 
echo "Result: $result"

CURL_OUTPUT: {"status":"INITIALIZED","result":"NONE"}
Status: INITIALIZED
Result: NONE
```

Comment: If I run this echo command alone I am able to get it . When I am using this in bash I am getting an additional '' before and after value.

Comment: echo $CURL_OUTPUT | awk -F: '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}'

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: I am storing Json in a variable called CURL_OUTPUT in my bash and I am getting the result of echo like "2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1"

Comment: echo $CURL_OUTPUT | awk -F: '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' | sed 's/"//;'

Comment: double quote before the value are gone. Still getting double quotes after the value. I am getting the output as

Comment: 2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1"

Comment: My bad: echo $CURL_OUTPUT | awk -F: '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}' | sed 's/"//g;'

Comment: Thank you so much its working. Can I have similar command to get the value of the key '"status" in below json

Comment: {"status":"INITIALIZED","result":"NONE"}

Comment: Actuallyt I need both Status and result in separate variables

Comment: I've modified the original answer, have a look. Also, please mark it as correct if it's helpful. ;)

Comment: Looks like its not reading the second value. I am getting the output like

Comment: Status: INITIALIZED
Result: result

Comment: The commands you gave work for the variable you declared. My CURL_OUTPUT just contains {"status":"INITIALIZED","result":"NONE"} without " at the beginning and end

Comment: The enclosing quotes are just to declare the variable, they're not part of it. See the output above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Working now

Answer (score 2):

Since PowerShell is tagged and if that is truly the entire JSON object, then:

```
('{"requestId":"2ef095c8-cec6-4fb2-a4fc-3c036f9ffaa1"}' | ConvertFrom-Json).requestId
```